# What is the probability that all 3 will be consonants?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is mainly a sanity check, because it wouldn't be the first time I discovered this textbook is wrong about something. See question #3 here:

[image: Question 3]

I've tried calculating by hand
$$ \frac{(21!/(3!(21-3)!) }{ (26!/(3!(26-3)!))}$$, punching it carefully into my calculator, and checking against Wolfram Alpha, and I always get 51%.

How did this textbook come up with 82%? Is the formulation of C(21, 3)/C(26, 3) correct or incorrect?

EDIT:

Lookie here, I just wrote an empirical test using python and the results are closer to my answer: 
[image: Python Script]

Comment: There is something weird indeed in the book. It states that ${21 \choose 3}$ would be $54~264$, but actually it's $1~330$. A HUGE difference ... hmmm ... $\frac{ { 21 \choose 3} }{  {  26 \choose 3  } }$ is indeed approximately $0.511~538$. Perhaps the maker has made a typo, because$$
{21 \choose 6} = 54~264 \quad \text{and} \quad {26 \choose 5} = 65~780
$$

Comment: Yeah that's weird... I even just wrote a little test to try this in an empirical way, and it's definitely about 51%.

Comment: So my answer is: You are correct, the book is wrong.